# Xamarin Forms waiting to call ASMX web service till after LoadApplication

Tags: c#, web-services, xamarin, xamarin.forms, asmx

I am working on an ASMX web service application in Xamarin Forms. I have successfully implemented my own service using the example below:

https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/WebServices/TodoASMX/

The issue I'm having is, the service is getting called immediately on the application load. Here is a little run down of what I'm trying to achieve:

1. App is loaded to a login page where the customer will enter in credentials. Login credentials are validated by hitting a web API.
2. After login, a modal page with a list of configurations retrieved from the API for that customer is shown. The customer will select a configuration which will include the soap url, user key for authentication, etc.
3. Once the configuration is selected, the app goes to the home screen and here is where I would like to start the connection to the ASMX web service.

I have this working successfully so far except for part 3. The issue is in both MainActivity.cs and AppDelegate.cs, before

```
LoadApplication(new App());
```

I have

```
App.ToDoManager = new ToDoItemManager(new SoapService());
```

There is a SoapService.cs class in both iOS and Android projects (as in the ToDoASMX example) and so this block is getting run on the app load:

```
 public SoapService()
{
   _service = new ToDoService.ToDoService();
   _service.Url = SoapUrl;
   ...
}
```

Is there a way to not call

```
App.ToDoManager = new ToDoItemManager(new SoapService());
```

until after the configuration has been selected? Right now I'm having to hard code the soap url.

I'm relatively new to Xamarin, so any tips/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: do you really need SoapService.cs in both projects?  Can't it be in the shared project?  If it's in shared code then calling it from your Login code should be trivial.

Comment: @Jason according to the example, I do need a SoapService.cs in both projects. I add the web reference in each platform project and have to create a proxy class (the SoapService.cs) to communicate with that.

Comment: I don't see anything in that code that looks platform specific.  Not sure why they did it that way.

Comment: @Jason Here is the only other ASMX example I could find. And they do it that way too. https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/consuming-asmx-services-in-xamarin-forms/ If you know of a better way to do this please let me know!